# Como saber quantos pixels tem um div com height:100%? E como posso subtrair determinado valor desse total de pixels e aplicar o que sobrou a outra div

Tags: jquery

Eu nao sei ao certo como posso fazer isso, mas no meu caso eu gostaria de subtrair 80 pixels de uma div que possui `height:100%`.

Vi que tem como pegar a altura de uma div, porem eu gostaria de fazer algo que eu creio que seja mais complexo!

Como já diz a pergunta "como saber quantos pixels tem um div com height:100%? E como posso subtrair determinado valor desse total de pixels e aplicar o que sobrou a outra div".

Ou seja, quero que no inicio do carregamento da pagina um código qualquer pegue converta os 100% de altura da div A em pixels. Ex: 100% = 500 pixels, desses 500 pixels eu gostaria de subtrair um valor qualquer, no meu caso 80 pixels, dessa forma sobrara um total de 420 pixels, e eu gostaria que esses 420 pixels fosse aplicada a outra div.
Isso é possível? Se sim, como?

Comment: Resposta editada pois havia um pequeno erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fazendo com javascript puro, o que lhe pode lhe oferecer um desempenho melhor, basta utilizar a função clientHeight para pegar a altura da div em pixels em seguida aplicar a outra div o resultado da subtração:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var altura = document.getElementById('geral').clientHeight;
    alert(altura);
    var alturaDaOutraDiv = parseInt(altura) - 80;
    if(alturaDaOutraDiv > 0){
        document.getElementById('outra').style.height= alturaDaOutraDiv+"px";
        var alturaDaOutra = document.getElementById('outra').clientHeight;
        alert(alturaDaOutra);
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="geral">
    Oi eu sou uma div com conteudo html.
    <p>Oi</p>
    <p>Oi</p>
    <p>Oi</p>
    <p>Oi</p>
    <p>Oi</p>
    <p>Oi</p>
    <p>Oi</p>
    
</div>
<div id="outra">
    conteudo da outra div
</div>
```

**Teste: http://jsfiddle.net/ysz4a1wr/3/**

Comment: Realmente funciono. Porém funciono só no jsfiddle no localhost não funciono!

Comment: @ivanveloso você deve usar `window.onload` ou com jquery `$(document).ready` - editei a resposta teste em seu localhost

Comment: Agora sim deu certo @GuilhermeNascimento, valeu